# ¿Como puedo obtener todos los datos de un JSON en Android?

Tags: java, php, android, json

Estoy realizando una aplicación android la cual consulta una base de datos para obtener el nombre de varios deportes.
La consulta que hago es la siguiente:

```
if($resultset=getSQLResultSet("SELECT etiqueta_nombre from sdo_v_etiquetas_espacios GROUP BY etiqueta_nombre")){
     while ($row = $resultset->fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM)){
        echo json_encode($row);
     }
}
```

Y devuelve el siguiente resultado: `["Futbol"]["Tenis"]`.
El código que implementa la extracción de datos despues de la consulta que tengo hecho es:

```
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        JSONArray ja = null;
        try {
            ja = new JSONArray(result);
            if(!ja.isNull(0)){
                for(int i=0;i<ja.length();i++)
                    etiquetas.add(ja.getString(i).toString());
            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

El problema está en que solo me devuelve el primero y si intento poner un `for` con la longitud de `ja.length()` devuelve un `OutOfIndex`.

Comment: edita el código de como creas el FOR, porque el ejemplo que has pasado te funciona ya que haces referencia solo a la posición 0.

Comment: Cambiado queda, el problema creo que es al realizar la consulta en PHP según la respuesta del compañero.

Comment: Buenas tardes, En el código anterior, qué viene siendo 'etiquetas'? Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

El formato de ese JSON no es válido, en formato correcto sería debería ser algo asi:

```
["Futbol", "Tenis"]
```

Para futuras referencias, puedes usar [este](http://jsonlint.com/) validador para comprobar el formato de tus JSON.

Con un formato como el que te menciono, el procesamiento sería tan sencillo como:

```
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

    JSONArray ja = new JSONArray(result);

    for(int i = 0; i < ja.length(); i++)
        etiquetas.add(ja.getString(i));

}
```

Comment: De acuerdo, en ese caso, cual sería la manera correcta de realizar la consulta PHP para que devolviera el formato que indicas? Gracias

Comment: Lo siento @Ivan, pero con PHP no puedo ayudarte.

Comment: @PabloSimonDiEstefano el JSON que propongo sí es válido, es un array de Strings, el que tú propones es un array de objetos, que es diferente. Puedes comprobar la válidez de JSONs en validadores como [este](https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com) y puedes ver una explicación sencilla en [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_arrays.asp)

Comment: @PabloSimonDiEstefano un error en el formato de las comillas, ¿en serio?...

Comment: @PabloSimonDiEstefano muy bien, enhorabuena entonces, una aportación muy interesante...

Comment: Recuerda ir borrando los comentarios obsoletos para dejar *limpia* la publicacion, @AdrianMenendez. Además intenta no dejar mensajes como el ultimo que no aportan nada constructivo y podria ser reportado

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que estas imprimiendo en cada iteracion tu JSON (en el PHP),

```
 $result = array();
if($resultset=getSQLResultSet("SELECT etiqueta_nombre from sdo_v_etiquetas_espacios GROUP BY etiqueta_nombre")){
 while ($row = $resultset->fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM)){
    $result[]=$row;
 }
}

echo json_encode($result)
```